# Why does fatal error "LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Program.obj'" occur when I compile a C++ project in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-c++, linker

I've created a new C++ project in Visual Studio 2008.  No code has been written yet;  Only project settings have been changed.

When I compile the project, I receive the following fatal error:

> fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Program.obj'

Answer (score 170, accepted):

This particular issue is caused by specifying a dependency to a lib file that had spaces in its path.  The path needs to be surrounded by quotes for the project to compile correctly.

On the **Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input** tab of the project’s properties, there is an **Additional Dependencies** property.  This issue can be fixed by adding the quotes. For example, changing this property from:

> C:\Program Files\sofware
> sdk\lib\library.lib

To:

> "C:\Program Files\sofware
> sdk\lib\library.lib"

where I added the quotes.

Comment: God you've just hanged two day's bug chase to 30 second one :)

Comment: I had the same problem. If your Linker is correct but your lib directory is set incorrectly the same error may come up. Try looking in **Configuration Properties -> VC++ directories -> Library Directories** to see if you set the library correctly. Sometimes the lib folder consists of a x86 and a x64 folder. You have to set it to one of those (depending on your compiler) rather than the folder containing both.

Comment: Don't forget to put a semicolon after `"C:\Program Files\sofware sdk\lib\library.lib"`. The absence of a `;` will also cause the project to compile incorrectly.

Comment: Had this problem while trying to build OpenCV using Visual Studio 2005 (on Windows 8.1)...and it solved it. Great!

Comment: MasterMind:  $(VC_LibraryPath_x86);$(WindowsSDK_LibraryPath_x86);   What do I change these to?

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work to me.   **"Qt5Xmld.lib";"Qt5XmlPatternsd.lib";"Qt5Cored.lib";%(AdditionalDependencies)** -What should I chage?

Comment: At first I thought the separator should be one space, at last I found it should be newline, i.e. one lib one line.

Comment: how do i get to the Configuration Properties screen?

Comment: The easiest way to find the guilty path (since C:\Program is of little help) is to check the linker command line arguments. (got to `Property Pages > Configuration Properties > Linker > Command Line`) It helps to copy paste that into a text editor ans search for `"Program "`.

Comment: Call me old school, but I never put spaces in anything when programming. It's always either ``camelCased`` or ``spaced_with_underscores``. I like to think that this technique has saved me at least a few dozen headaches through the years.

Comment: In my case I accidentally erased the ```%``` in front of ```%(CoreLibraryDependencies)```

Answer (score 79):

This can happen if the file is still running as well.

> :-1: error: LNK1104: cannot open file 'debug\****.exe'

Comment: this was my problem too!

Comment: I get this caused by MS Security Essentials keeping the file locked.

Comment: yep, closed the previous console window and suddenly the lib could be read.

Comment: I signed-out and signed-in again, which worked. Apparently I had no open *.exe file running, and tried restarting VS, with no effect.

Comment: I found my ,exe file is open, yet. I close it with task manager.

Answer (score 17):

The problem went away for me after closing and re-opening Visual Studio. Not sure why the problem happened, but that might be worth a shot.

This was on VS 2013 Ultimate, Windows 8.1.

Comment: ah, Microsoft... Our first try should always be close and reopen (or power off and on) - several mysterious bugs goes away when we do that...

Comment: I feel so shameful that this solution can solve my problem.  Now, I can't go outside to meet my friends and family anymore.

Comment: You had the same problem as Carol.

Answer (score 10):

Check also that you don't have this turned on: **Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocess to a File**.

Comment: In my case it was also the issue, yet , what should I do if I do wish to turn this flag on (in order to view the Prepossessed file) ?

Comment: You've got some workarounds here: [How to output preprocessed code AND compile it (Visual Studio)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7826243/how-to-output-preprocessed-code-and-compile-it-visual-studio) and here: [Compiling a project (VS 2008) with the /p argument (preprocess to a file) doesn't compile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570024/compiling-a-project-vs-2008-with-the-p-argument-preprocess-to-a-file-doesn). But essentially it's a compiler option so it will do either but not both.

Answer (score 9):

My problem was a missing `.lib` extension, I was just linking against `mylib` and VS decided to look for `mylib.obj`.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem.It caused by a "," in the name of a folder of additional library path.It solved by changing the additional library path.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, but solution for my case is not listed in answers.
My antivirus program (AVG) determined file `MyProg.exe` as a virus and put it into the 'virus storehouse'. You need to check this storehouse and if file is there - then just restore it. It helped me out.

Comment: same here! BitDefender is blocking the access to the file.

Answer (score 4):

Solution 1 (for my case): restart windows Explorer process (yes, the windows file manager).

Solution 2:

1. Close Visual Studio. Windows Logoff
2. Logon, reopen Visual Studio
3. Build as usual. It now builds and can access the problematic file.

I presume sometimes the file system or whoever is controlling it gets lost with its permissions. Before restarting the windows session, tried to kill zombie `msbuild32.exe` processes, restart visual studio, check none even showing the problem file on. No build configuration issues. It happens now and then. Some internal thing in Windows does not fix up, needs a restart.

Comment: I had this problem with VS2019... this fixed it... amazing that bugs persist. thx

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was a matter of a mis-directed reference.  Project referenced the output of another project but the latter did not output the file where the former was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error, just with a Nuget package i had installed (one that is not header only) and then tried to uninstall.
What was wrong for me was that i was still including a header for the package i just uninstalled in one of my .cpp files (pretty silly, yes).
I even removed the additional library directories link to it in `Project -> Properties -> Linker -> General`, but of course to no avail since i was still trying to reference the non-existent header.

Definitely a confusing error message in this case, since the header name was `<boost/filesystem.hpp>` but the error gave me `"cannot open file 'llibboost_filesystem-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib'"` and no line numbers or anything.

Answer (score 2):

in my case it was the path lenght (incl. file name).

```
..\..\..\..\..\..\..\SWX\Binary\VS2008\Output\Win32\Debug\boost_unit_test_framework-vc90-mt-gd-1_57.lib;
```

as for the release the path was (this has worked correctly):

```
..\..\..\..\..\..\..\SWX\Binary\VS2008\Output\Win32\Release\boost_unit_test_framework-vc90-mt-1_57.lib;
```

==> one char shorter.

1. i have also verified this by renaming the lib file (using shorter name) and changing this in the

*Linker -> input -> additoinal dependencies*

2. i have also verified this by adding absolut path instead of relative path as all those ".." has extended the path string, too. this has also worked.

**so the problem for me was the total size of the path + filename string was too long!**

Comment: +1 for this, beware of the 260 character Windows path length limit that can easily be reached when complicated toolchains start creating temporary files inside of temporary directories inside of well-nested project folders.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. I solved it with the following command to kill the running task:

> taskkill /f /im [nameOfExe]

/f: Forces the task to close.
/im: The next parameter is a image name aka executable name e.g. Program.exe.

Answer (score 1):

For an assembly project (ProjectName -> Build Dependencies -> Build Customizations -> masm (selected)), setting **Generate Preprocessed Source Listing** to **True** caused the problem for me too, clearing the setting fixed it. VS2013 here.

Answer (score 1):

I run into the same problem with linker complaining about the main executable missing. This happened during our solution port to the new **Visual Studio 2013**. The solution is a varied mix of managed and un-managed projects/code. The problem (and fix) ended up being a missing ***app.config*** file in the solution folder. Took a day to figure this one out :(, as output log was not very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I checked all my settings according to this list: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts7eyw4s.aspx#feedback . It is helpful to me and for my situation, I find out that Link Dependency of projects' properties has double-quote, which should not be there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering because I don't see this particular solution listed by anyone else.

Apparently my antivirus (Ad-Aware) was flagging a DLL one of my projects depends on, and deleting it. Even after excluding the directory where the DLL lives, the same behaviour continued until I restarted my computer.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had replaced math library files from a previous Game Engine Graphics course with GLM. The problem was that I didn't add them to the project within Visual Studio's Solution Explorer (even though they were in the project repository).

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in conjunction with the LNK2038 error, followed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668200/error-lnk2038-mismatch-detected-for-iterator-debug-level-value-0-doesnt) to segregate the RELEASE and the DEBUG DLLs. In this process I had cleaned up the whole folder where these dependencies were residing.

Luckily I had a backup of all these files, and got the file for which this error was throwing back into the DEBUG folder to resolve the issue. The error code was misleading in some way as I had to spend a lot of time to come to this tip from one of the answers from this post again.

Hope this answer, helps someone in need.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by **adding** an **existing project** **to** my **solution**, which I **forgot to add** in the first time.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error:

```
fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'GTest.lib;'
```

This was caused by the `;` at the end. If you have multiple libraries, they should be separated by empty space (spacebar), no comma or semi-colons!

So don't use `;` or any anything else when listing libraries in <kbd>Project properties >> Configuration Properties >> Linker >> Input</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I tried above solution but didnt work for me.
So i rename the exe and rebuild the solution.
It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact error when building a VC++ DLL in Visual Studio 2019:

> LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Program.obj'

Turned out under project Properties > Linker > Input > Module Definition File, I had specified a def file that had **an unmatched double-quote** at the end of the filename.  Deleting the unmatched double quote resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Killed `msbuild32.exe` and built again. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was caused by **other application using the .dll** file I was trying to debug.

**Closing** the application that was **using the .dll solved it for me.**

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions:

1. Check if path contain any white spaces, Go to Properties > Linker > Input > additional path and include "path with white space"
2. If program are still running, close everything and restart.
3. Check if .obj file is not created. This happens when you directly build a project while Properties > C++ > Preprocessor > Generate preprocessor file is on. Turn it off and build the project then you can onn Properties > C++ > Preprocessor > Generate preprocessor file.

Answer (score -1):

I hit the same problem with "Visual Studio 2013".

```
LNK1104: cannot open file 'debug\****.exe
```

**It resolved after closing and re-starting Visual studio.**

Answer (score -4):

I was having the same problem , I have just copied the code to new project and started the build . 
Some other error started coming. 
error C4996: 'fopen': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using fopen_s instead

To solve this problem again, I have added my one property in the Project project as below. 
Project -> Properties -> Configuration property -> c/c++ . 
In this category there is field name Preprocessor Definitions
I have added _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS this to solve the problem
Hope it will help ...

Thank You

Comment: This answer has no relation with theoriginal post.

Comment: Not to mention disabling the security features is not exactly a good idea