# Strange Link Error in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, windows-7, linker-errors

I use Visual Studio 2008 pro in Windows 7. I got a strange link error when trying to compile a simple C++ code. It was **fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Users\CSE.obj'**. Any idea what the cause is and how to get over it??

My Windows user account is named as 'CSE User 15'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your path has spaces in it! Check out this page:
[Why does fatal error "LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Program.obj'" occur when I compile a C++ project in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133698/why-does-fatal-error-lnk1104-cannot-open-file-c-program-obj-occur-when-i-co)