# C++ link error - cannot open file 'omniorb414_rtd.lib'

Tags: c++, visual-studio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does fatal error “LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Program.obj'” occur when I compile a C++ project in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133698/why-does-fatal-error-lnk1104-cannot-open-file-c-program-obj-occur-when-i-co)

Can you let me know what this error means in c++
    fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'omniorb414_rtd.lib'

Comment: It means that the linker cannot find omniorb414_rtd.lib - Check your linker input paths

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133698/why-does-fatal-error-lnk1104-cannot-open-file-c-program-obj-occur-when-i-co

Comment: Please choose more descriptive titles for your questions. "C++ Programming" could cover literally anything.

Answer (score 1):

In Configuration Properties->Linker->General add the path to the directory your library lives in under Additional library Directories.

The path should be "C:\Dev\3rdPartytoolkits" according to your comment.