# How can I solve errors coming in C++ OpenXLSX library

Tags: c++, visual-studio, openxlsx

It's my first time using an external library in my project, I am using [OpenXLSX](https://github.com/troldal/OpenXLSX) library for reading **XLSX** files.

I followed the procedure given in their official git repo:
First I had to clone repo, then build the code with the help of CMake, and then install that library.

After that I had to include it's path into my project properties, and into linker as well.

Then after everything is done, I am running the demo example given inside the library itself, but it's giving numerous errors (125+) ,mostly of them turns out to be indicating that the syntax inside the library files is wrong !
Here is some example of the errors coming:

> C:\Work\C++\tryingOpenXLSX1\include\OpenXLSX\headers\XLCellValue.hpp(112,74): error C2039: 'string_view': is not a member of 'std'

> C:\Work\C++\tryingOpenXLSX1\include\OpenXLSX\headers\XLCellValue.hpp(199,74): error C2039: 'string_view': is not a member of 'std'

> C:\Work\C++\tryingOpenXLSX1\include\OpenXLSX\headers\XLCellValue.hpp(150,21): error C3861: 'm_value': identifier not found

These are just few examples, I am getting errors out of library's files.

Now, I am not sure why this is happening, repo is cloned from latest version, my IDE (VS 2022) etc everything is updated.

Comment: `C2039: 'string_view': is not a member of 'std'` -- Did you set the Language in your project settings to C++17?  By default VS has the language set to C++14, which does not recognize `std::string_view`.  [Possible duplicate](/questions/64042721/std-has-no-member-filesystem-in-c-17)

Comment: thanks for pointing it out, and it was indeed set default to C++ 14, However after changing that it's again errors which are of different nature this time :                                        1>OpenXLSX.lib(XLCellValue.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in Source.obj

Comment: This might help for the new error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668200/error-lnk2038-mismatch-detected-for-iterator-debug-level-value-0-doesnt.

Answer (score 0):

So, basically what was happening :

> I was following the instructions given on official github repository,
> which were intended to build that library in 'Release' configuration,
> so when my IDE was debugging it, it was throwing errors.

Solution to it is:

> Build library with specifying configuration to 'Debug' (using CMake
> ofcourse) and then also install it in 'Debug' configuration.