# How to output preprocessed code AND compile it (Visual Studio)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cuda, c-preprocessor

I'm generating preprocessor output (.i) from Visual Studio, but also want to do the actual build. Is there a combination of flags that will both output the .i file without then stopping the compiler from going ahead with the build as normal?

This is currently just C++ but will probably want to use this with CUDA later, so prefer answers that work within Visual Studio rather than require command line (unless it works for CUDA too).

The point of this is to save the time it takes to do Project->Properties->Config Props->C/C++->Preprocessor->Generate Preprocessed File Yes/No plus Rebuild. Particularly it is irksome to me that the preprocessor has to run twice, so a solution that somehow generates the .i file in part 1 and then compiles that file in part 2 would be fine.

The exact version of Visual Studio I'm using is VS 2008 Express

Answer (score 2):

You can add a custom build step or a new target to dump the preprocess after the code is built by definition the dumped preprocessor output is what is built.

Comment: Either way, the build has to read the files twice?  But that's the slow part!

Comment: Custom target could cpp build the *.i as long as it depends on the target that dumps the preprocessor.

Comment: *blink* Whoa... That could work, and possibly generate a more efficient file due to the linker knowing more...

Comment: OK great - managed it without the .bat file. Here's what I did: 1. Add the .i file to the project 2. in Solution Explorer, right click on the .i file->Configuration Properties->Tool->C/C++ Compiler Tool 3. Rebuild solution (Ctrl-Alt-F7) - this will fail as it will have copied the same compiler options, which include preprocessor output 4. repeat step 2, now you should see all the normal compiler options in a subtree, select Preprocessor and turn off preprocessor output for the .i file (obivously) 5. build again - now it works - hurrah

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom build config that does pre-processing and then define a batch build that builds the pre-processed version followed by the actual compiled / linked version.

Comment: OK great this sounds ideal. By "custom build config" do you mean the "custom build step" that the previous guy mentioned? If so there's a nice progression here :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use the switch /P Example- cl /C sample.c

The above will generate a .I file with same name (sample.I). Now to compile the .I file, just rename .I file to .C then do cl /c to compile and generate an object file.

Answer (score 0):

If your running GNU gcc/g++ compiler, then configure a Makefile target "recipe" with the following code

```
gcc -save-temps -dumpbase save-foo -c foo.c
```

Reference can be found in the terminal man pages for gcc.

```
man gcc
```

section:

> -dumpbase *dumpbase*

This will create a separate .i file and compile "foo" to object code. That code can then be used as a prerequisite for your target "goal" executable. Link below explains the vocabulary I used.

https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Simple-Makefile.html#Simple-Makefile