# Eclipse can't link to kernel32.lib

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I've installed Eclipse CDT so I'll be able to write and compile C code.

The compilation progress fails and the following error appears:

```
LNK1104 : cannot open file kernel32.lib
```

I've been searching for this file in my computer and found out it appears in some folders,

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Lib
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Lib
```

How could I "refer" eclipse to one of this certain paths so the `kernel32.lib` file will be found and I'll be able to compile and run `C` files?

**EDIT**
Thanks to @mux answer the     `LNK1104 : cannot open file kernel32.lib` is now gone , but a new error appears now :     `LNK1104 : cannot open file 'C:\Program.lib'` .
Once again, any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: This may be helpful http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/300603

Comment: Just for your information - the code is compiled fine, it's a linking error (the linking fails, not the compilation).

Answer (score 11):

i wasted a lot of time on this...
this is the answer you are searching for

In Eclipse > Project > Properties > Paths and Symbols > Libraries tab, enclose the path to the library in single quotes:

'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Lib\Kernel32.Lib'

There would be a warning that the path does not exist, but it should be gone after you rebuild your project.

Answer (score 7):

I've the same problem, I've fixed because of installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 on my computer:

1. Right click on your `C/C++ project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Environment`
2. In `LIB`, click on the Button `Edit` on the right side
3. Add `;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Lib`      <---- `;` to separate the first auto detected path"

*** Must be on the both Debug and Release configuration : else you'll get the same error ***

Answer (score 2):

you need to add the path to the library to your project, from the [FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#How_do_I_add_an_external_library_to_my_C.2B.2B_project.3F)

> Go to Your Project's Properties by right clicking on project's name
>   and selecting properties. Click on "C/C++ Build". Under Tool Settings
>   Tab, click on Directories. Click on The Add Button and Select
>   FileSystem. Select the folder with C/C++ libraries. Apply and then Ok.
>   The new library is included.

**Edit:**

The wiki seems outdated, but I did find the options relevant to linking here:

> C/C++ Build->Settings->Tool Settings tab

you should add the include paths for headers (if any) to the *compiler* `Includes` and the libraries to the *linker* options `Libraries(-l)` and the library path to `Library Search path (-L)`

Comment: A quote would make your answer a lot better.

Comment: The problem is that there isn't any "Tool Settings" tab under C/C++ Build ( I use eclipse indigo ) @mux

Comment: @mux , thanks for the answer, the kernel32.lib error is now gone , but a new error came up : now 'C:\Program.obj' is missing. any ideas ? Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Go to:
"Project Properties>c/c++ Build>Settings>c++ Linker>Libraries"
Add library kernel32 and set search path to your library or set LIBRARY_PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

For "LNK1104 : cannot open file kernel32.lib" error you need to include path to kernel32.lib in Eclipse > Project > Properties > Paths and Symbols > Libraries tab

For LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Program.obj' error you need to make sure the path you provided earlier is inside single quote('). [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133698/why-does-fatal-error-lnk1104-cannot-open-file-c-program-obj-occur-when-i-c)

Hope this solves your problem.