# LNK1104 error when installing libsvm in matlab

Tags: matlab, libsvm

I am not able to complete the installation of libsvm in matlab. When I run the make.m file I get the following error:

> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libsvmread.mexw64'
>
> C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2013A\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: Link of 'libsvmread.mexw64' failed.

Can anyone help me resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you sure you have [a compatible compiler for win64](https://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2014a/index.html)?

Comment: yes i have install the compatible compiler for win64

Comment: Can the problem be related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133698/why-does-fatal-error-lnk1104-cannot-open-file-c-program-obj-occur-when-i-c)?