# Class Account -output

Tags: c++, class

my program is about  making a class Account and I need to create 3 accounts that includes account number,type,owner's name,balance, and interest rate. and make a function for calculating the monthly interest.I wanna know what's wrong with my code because the output I'm getting is not right

```
   #ifndef ACCOUNT_H
        #define ACCOUNT_H
        class Account {

        public:
        Account(char* ='\0',char='S',char* ='\0',double=0.0,double=0.05);
        ~Account();
        void setaccounts(char*,char,char*,double,double);
        void setBalance(double);
        void setInterestRate(double);
        double getBalance(void);
        double getInterestRate(void);
        void monthlyInterest();

        void printAccounts();

        private:
        char AccountNumber[7];
        char type;
        char owner[30];
        double balance;
        double interestRate;

        };
        #endif
   #include<iostream>
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;
#include<cstring>

    #include"Account.h"
    Account::Account(char* accountnumber,char typee,char* Owner,double Balance,double Interestrate){

        AccountNumber[0]='\0';
        type='\0';
        owner[0]='\0';
        balance=0.0;
        interestRate=0.0;

    }

    Account::~Account(){

    }


    void Account::setaccounts(char* accountnumber1,char typee1,char* Owner1,double Balance1,double Interestrate1){

int length=strlen(accountnumber1);
length=(length==7?length:'\0');
       type=typee1;
        switch(typee1)
        {
        case 1:
            if(typee1=='S')
                cout<<"Saving accounts"<<endl;
                break;
        case 2:
            if(typee1=='C')
                cout<<"Checking accounts"<<endl;
                break;
        case 3:
            if(typee1=='L')

                cout<<"Loans accounts"<<endl;
                break;
        default:
            cout<<'S'<<endl;

        }

int length2=strlen(Owner1);
length2=(length2<30?length2:'\0');

balance=Balance1;
interestRate=Interestrate1;
    }
    void Account::setBalance(double bal){
    balance=bal>=0?bal:0;
        }
    double Account::getBalance(){
        return balance;

    }

     void Account::setInterestRate(double inter){
    interestRate=(inter>0 && inter<1)?inter:0.05;
        }

    double Account::getInterestRate(){

        return interestRate;
    }

    void  Account::monthlyInterest(){

     balance+=(balance*interestRate)/12;

    }
        void Account::printAccounts(){
        cout<<"The account number: "<<AccountNumber<<endl;
        cout<<"The account's type: "<<type<<endl;
        cout<<"The name of the account's owner"<<owner<<endl;
        cout<<"The balance-amount of money in USD currently existing in the account: "<<balance<<endl;
        cout<<"The annnual interest rate is :"<<interestRate<<endl;
        cout<<"The monthly interest is: "<<balance<<endl;
    }


    int main()
    {
        Account Acc, arrays[3],*theseaccounts;

        arrays[0].setaccounts("LAM1234",'C',"Sam Smith",5.3,0.6);                                                 
        arrays[1].setaccounts("JDM2345",'L',"Mark Wayne",4.3,0.2);
        arrays[2].setaccounts("HWN9342",'S',"Drake Bell",2.3,0.9);
        theseaccounts=&arrays[3];
        theseaccounts->printAccounts();
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
            arrays[i].printAccounts();
        }


    system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

A number of C-standard libraries are still technically available in C++, but their use is being discouraged, at least by some compilers. You have a few options:

1. Turn the warning off. Not really the best choice, but what you are doing is legal C++.
2. Replace strncpy by a safer alternative.
3. Use std::string instead of raw strings. This is BY FAR the best choice available to you.

Comment: ok thanks but I'm having another error which is fatal error LNK1104 :/

Comment: You can google for that sort of problem. I did so and found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133698/why-does-fatal-error-lnk1104-cannot-open-file-c-program-obj-occur-when-i-c