# opencv imgproc error ( C++ VS2012 )

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012

Alright, So here is the simple code, [**Error Snapshot and Output Log at the bottom**]

**Update:** I have already changed the library names (Debug+Release) from 248 to 2413)

**Update2:** Turning On: Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocess to a File changes the error to LNK1104 error>Line 1.

```
#include<opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
int main(void)
{
       Mat frame;
       frame=imread("room.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
       while (waitKey(30)!=27) //27 is ascii equivalent of esc key
       {
              imshow("Image", frame); //loop line 1
       }
}
```

---

Here are my **OpenCV configuration settings** I used for Visual Studio 2012 that I followed from this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v-VgWxkVp2w)

---

1. Download OpenCV 2.4.8 ( but I'm using version 2413]
2. Create a Win32 console application
3. Config opencv..
   3.1. Menu Project ---- $ProjectName Properties

3.2. Choose Configuration Manager... and add x64 platform

3.3. At configuration field, choose All configuration
3.3.1. At Configuration Properties ---- C/C++ ---- Additional Include Directories, add opencv include folders

```
$opencv\build\include
$opencv\build\opencv
$opencv\build\opencv2
```

NOTE: $opencv is a folder that you have installed opencv

3.3.2. At Configuration Properties ---- Linker ---- Additional Library Directories, add opencv library folder
$opencv\build\x64\vc11\lib

3.4. At configuration field, choose Debug mode
3.4.1. At Configuration Properties ---- Linker ---- Additional dependencies ----

add dependence libraries
    opencv_stitching248d.lib
    opencv_contrib248d.lib
    opencv_videostab248d.lib
    opencv_superres248d.lib
    opencv_nonfree248d.lib
    opencv_gpu248d.lib
    opencv_ocl248d.lib
    opencv_legacy248d.lib
    opencv_ts248d.lib
    opencv_calib3d248d.lib
    opencv_features2d248d.lib
    opencv_objdetect248d.lib
    opencv_highgui248d.lib
    opencv_video248d.lib
    opencv_photo248d.lib
    opencv_imgproc248d.lib
    opencv_flann248d.lib
    opencv_ml248d.lib
    opencv_core248d.lib

NOTE: These file above are located at .\opencv\build\x64\vc11\lib\

3.5. At configuration field, choose Release mode
3.5.1. At Configuration Properties ---- Linker ---- Additional dependencies ---- add dependence libraries
    opencv_stitching248.lib
    opencv_contrib248.lib
    opencv_videostab248.lib
    opencv_superres248.lib
    opencv_nonfree248.lib
    opencv_gpu248.lib
    opencv_ocl248.lib
    opencv_legacy248.lib
    opencv_ts248.lib
    opencv_calib3d248.lib
    opencv_features2d248.lib
    opencv_objdetect248.lib
    opencv_highgui248.lib
    opencv_video248.lib
    opencv_photo248.lib
    opencv_imgproc248.lib
    opencv_flann248.lib
    opencv_ml248.lib
    opencv_core248.lib
NOTE: These file above are located at .\opencv\build\x64\vc11\lib\

3.6. Add $opencv\build\x64\v11\bin to System Environment Path
3.7. Restart Visual studio

---

So previously it was working with VC11, then I included imgproc in my code, and ever since this error doesn't seem to go away. I even tried using VC12.

Why I am seeing this error, I'm **not even using imgproc** in  my code?

Yes, I have been a good sport and I **searched like 20-25 related posts** but in vain. So I really need an expert's advice, who can be a beginner in this, because as you can see from the code I am completely **new to OpenCV**.

**Thanks** in advance people.

---

### OutPut:

1>------ Build started: Project: OpenCV2, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>  Source.cpp
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(141): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'ksize'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(141): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(142): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'anchor'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(142): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(224): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(224): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '<'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(234): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(234): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '<'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(241): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Size'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(243): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(243): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '&'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(249): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(249): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '&'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(260): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'ksize'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(260): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(261): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'anchor'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(261): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(263): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'wholeSize'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(263): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(264): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'roi'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(264): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(267): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(267): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(267): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(269): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(269): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(269): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(270): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(270): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(270): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(271): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(271): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(271): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(272): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(272): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(272): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(274): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(274): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(274): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(276): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(276): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(276): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(277): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(277): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(277): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(278): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(278): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(278): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(254): error C2065: 'filter2D' : undeclared identifier
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(286): error C2065: 'InputArray' : undeclared identifier
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(286): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'kernel'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(286): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(289): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(289): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(294): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(294): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(294): error C2086: 'int cv::Ptr' : redefinition
1>          D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(289) : see declaration of 'cv::Ptr'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(300): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(300): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(300): error C2086: 'int cv::Ptr' : redefinition
1>          D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(289) : see declaration of 'cv::Ptr'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(306): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(306): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(306): error C2086: 'int cv::Ptr' : redefinition
1>          D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(289) : see declaration of 'cv::Ptr'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(314): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(314): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(314): error C2086: 'int cv::Ptr' : redefinition
1>          D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(289) : see declaration of 'cv::Ptr'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(320): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'getGaussianKernel'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(320): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(323): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(323): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(323): error C2086: 'int cv::Ptr' : redefinition
1>          D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(289) : see declaration of 'cv::Ptr'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(327): error C2065: 'OutputArray' : undeclared identifier
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(327): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'kx'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(327): error C2182: 'getDerivKernels' : illegal use of type 'void'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(329): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(331): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(331): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(331): error C2086: 'int cv::Ptr' : redefinition
1>          D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(289) : see declaration of 'cv::Ptr'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(335): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(335): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(335): error C2086: 'int cv::Ptr' : redefinition
1>          D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(289) : see declaration of 'cv::Ptr'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(338): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(338): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(338): error C2086: 'int cv::Ptr' : redefinition
1>          D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(289) : see declaration of 'cv::Ptr'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(342): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(342): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(342): error C2086: 'int cv::Ptr' : redefinition
1>          D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(289) : see declaration of 'cv::Ptr'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(348): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'getGaborKernel'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(348): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(348): error C2086: 'int cv::Mat' : redefinition
1>          D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(320) : see declaration of 'cv::Mat'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(348): error C2065: 'Size' : undeclared identifier
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(348): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'ksize'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(349): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(358): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(358): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(358): error C2086: 'int cv::Ptr' : redefinition
1>          D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(289) : see declaration of 'cv::Ptr'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(360): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(360): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(360): error C2086: 'int cv::Ptr' : redefinition
1>          D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(289) : see declaration of 'cv::Ptr'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(362): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(362): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(362): error C2086: 'int cv::Ptr' : redefinition
1>          D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(289) : see declaration of 'cv::Ptr'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(366): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'morphologyDefaultBorderValue'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(366): error C2433: 'Scalar' : 'inline' not permitted on data declarations
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(366): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(366): error C2825: 'cv::Scalar': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(366): error C2039: 'all' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(366): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'all'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(366): error C3861: 'all': identifier not found
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(369): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(369): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(369): error C2086: 'int cv::Ptr' : redefinition
1>          D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(289) : see declaration of 'cv::Ptr'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(377): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'getStructuringElement'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(377): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(377): error C2086: 'int cv::Mat' : redefinition
1>          D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(320) : see declaration of 'cv::Mat'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(377): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Size'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(379): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(379): error C2182: 'Ptr' : illegal use of type 'void'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(379): error C2086: 'int cv::Ptr' : redefinition
1>          D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(289) : see declaration of 'cv::Ptr'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(379): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(379): error C2059: syntax error : '<'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(379): error C2039: 'delete_obj' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(387): error C2065: 'InputArray' : undeclared identifier
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(387): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'src'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(387): error C2182: 'medianBlur' : illegal use of type 'void'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(387): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(389): error C2065: 'InputArray' : undeclared identifier
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(389): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'src'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(389): error C2182: 'GaussianBlur' : illegal use of type 'void'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(392): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(394): error C2065: 'InputArray' : undeclared identifier
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(394): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'src'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(394): error C2182: 'bilateralFilter' : illegal use of type 'void'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(396): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(398): error C2065: 'InputArray' : undeclared identifier
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(398): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'src'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(398): error C2182: 'adaptiveBilateralFilter' : illegal use of type 'void'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(400): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(400): fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

---

[ERROR SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSdsT.jpg)

Comment: "Download OpenCV 2.4.8 ( but I'm using version 2413]" -- HUH?

Comment: Anything man, I'm willing to try it cause I'm new. But how does that justify that my OpenCV 2.4.1.3 version initially worked?

Comment: #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

Comment: Should the version number even make a difference here? 
I just opened the download page for OpenCV
http://opencv.org/downloads.html
and v2.4.8 is nowhere to be found. What should I do now?

Comment: @DanMašek I appreciate your comment, please help me get there.

Comment: @Miki Just did, still the same error as you see in the screenshot.

Comment: @WikiMalik 2.4.13 is fine, might as well use a recent version. However, the entire question talks about 2.4.8, especially all the .lib files still have `248` in the name, rather than `2413`. That's bit misleading.

Comment: @DanMašek I changed the 248 to 2413 for both Debug and Release. I have checked it like 20 times. I wish it were the problem.

Comment: Is there more info I can provide that could help?

Comment: @Miki Surely that should not be needed, unless `highgui.hpp` doesn't include all it uses (which I would consider a pretty bad bug). As shown, that code sample builds fine for me on VS2013, so that's not the case.

Comment: @WikiMalik My point was that big parts of your question say you did A, but in fact you did B. Anyway, bad lib names wouldn't cause compile errors. Rather than a screenshot of the error list (and lots of other stuff), attach the text from the "Output" window.

Comment: @DanMašek Okay, tried to add it to the main thread but I really have a bad reputation. here's the link to the text file. 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_wIR1AsbUQvWnhLWnhyYU1TbE0/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

It's a compiler error (not a linker error)  so it should have to do with the header files, I guess.
Haven't you installed different versions of OpenCV on the same place? That would mix up the things.
Try delete all the opencv files and start over again.

Comment: No, there is no other version of OpenCV installed on my computer. Two facts keep bugging me.
1. Why was it working before and now it's not (after I included imgproc in my code, which later removing isn't doing any better)?
2. Why is error log saying that the error is in the imgproc library?

It's been two days, I'm still scratching my head over the problem. Can do you know someone who can help me? I really appreciate your answer and I'd love to find the one that finally solves my problem.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mistakenly modify the opencv header file? Check around the first error (imgproc.hpp(141)) to see if there's anything strange. Or, check the file timestamp.

Comment: I created another project using the same configuration, still the same error. Had it been the header file issue, it should have been gone. But I'm all ears, if you think you are onto something, just tell me the step-wise instruction and I swear I will follow it without any questions.

Comment: Creating a new visual studio project won't clean up opencv header files. Please check imgproc.hpp and find what exactly is causing the syntax error. Then you will be getting close to the problem.

Comment: Great, let's focus on that. The problem is I won't be able to understand the error, the output log is right there and I am completely new to OpenCV and visual studio. (Java, HTML, C# would have been my thing) Tell me what you need, file, text, anything... I'll update it on the thread or create a temporary blog for you to read.

Comment: Can you replace the first line with

Comment: Can you replace the first line with `#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>` ?

Comment: Didn't you delete `#include "stdafx.h"` generated automatically by visual studio ? This is necessary to be in the very first line for every .cpp files with precompiled header enabled, which is the default. And missing this might have caused your problem.

Comment: I didn't delete any file of the project if that's what you are pointing to. Or did to mean I have to include it in the code? I did that to due to my desperation... no result?

Comment: From this forum, Patrizio Bertonis' answer looks like the exact problem I get when I turn on: Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocess to a File (as instructed by Nikita.. A linker error, you might be familar with?)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133698/why-does-fatal-error-lnk1104-cannot-open-file-c-program-obj-occur-when-i-c

Comment: When you create a win32 console app, it should look like this.`// ConsoleApplication1.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
 return 0;
}
`

Comment: Sorry for the broken text but I still don't know how to write a comment with line breaks. Anyway, `#include "stdafx.h"` is really vital part of the project. This defines all the necessary macros and symbols for preprocessors.

Answer (score 1):

In project options (3.3) you only need the following additional include:

```
$opencv\build\include
```

> D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(141): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'ksize' 1>D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp(141): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

Error caused by missed declaration of `Size` which is declared in `"opencv2/core/core.hpp"` header. Other types like `InputArray`, `OutputArray` also declared there. `core.hpp` is included together with `#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>`. Check that `core.hpp` is not broken (e.g. not empty).

If you use Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate you can generate [include graph](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409453(v=vs.110).aspx) and check where `imgproc.hpp` included. For the program above it should looks like on the picture bellow:

[image]

As you can see, `imgproc.hpp` header is not included automatically. To fix the error you should find where `imgproc.hpp` is included. I suggest to check the preprocessor output for the `Source.cpp` file. To do it follow the instructions [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z9z0bx6.aspx). Look through the result `Source.i` file and find where `imgproc.hpp` included.

**UPDATE:**

In your `Source.i` the following lines includes `imgproc.hpp`:

```
#line 2 "d:\\program files (x86)\\microsoft visual studio 11.0\\vc\\include\\iosfwd"
#line 1 "d:\\opencv\\opencv\\build\\include\\opencv2\\imgproc\\imgproc.hpp"
```

these lines come from the standard headers includes in `#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"`. I don't know why this random header included there.

It looks like there is a magic to disable standard headers include. Define `SKIP_INCLUDES` in your preprocessor definitions. In Solution Explorer opens `Project Properties -> C\C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor Definitions` and add `SKIP_INCLUDES` there.

Comment: Also you can post link to `Source.i` here and I will check it.

Comment: Following your instructions,
1. Additional Include now only has: D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include
2. I checked the core.hpp, the file is about 186kb, so I think it's not empty.

Comment: 3. I don't have VS 2012 Ultimate, so I can't generate include graph, but I could get Ultimate if you recommend it.
4. Your last para got a little too techy for me, I followed your recommended link, but it wasn't fully clear. I could only get as far as this >> http://opencvtesting101.blogspot.com/2016/12/how-to-generate-preprocessor-output.html

Comment: 5. So if I think the purpose is to check imgproc.hpp's header, it should show in the included files. So I followed these >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137966/displaying-the-include-hierarchy-for-a-c-file-in-visual-studio << instructions to get the list of included files and headers >> http://opencvtesting101.blogspot.com/2016/12/included-files-and-headers.html (tried to update it on the main thread but we have already exaggerate wordcount limit, please ignore my noodledom and thanks for help, I appreciate it.)

Comment: If step 5. didn't help, please help me a bit with step 4. I am trying my best here to make sure I search and try before asking you more questions.

Comment: @WikiMalik Purpose of retrieving of `Source.i` is to understand who includes `imgproc.hpp` header. Steps to get this preprocessed file is simple: 1) In Solution Explorer open context menu for `Source.cpp` file and select Properties; 2) Than change `C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocess to a File -> Yes`. 3) Once again open context menu for `Source.cpp` and click `Compile`. 4) Result file `Source.i` will be in intermediate folder "x64\Debug" or something like that.

Comment: Thanks for guiding me through the process, here's the link to source.i file that was generated in the Solution\Project\Debug folder.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_wIR1AsbUQvMTdka2tMWDNQOUU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: While I do believe it's way above me, I'll also try to put my finger on the file in the light of your explanation of the error. Thanks again. BTW I have changed all the configurations to x86 just to experiment with it, but if I have an x64 backup of the project so that won't be a problem.

Comment: Update: Turning On: Preprocessor -> Preprocess to a File changes the error to LNK1104 error>Line 1.

Comment: @WikiMalik Right, Proprocessor output is required only to understand what is going on during compilation. Please disable it and try to apply workaround from my updated answer.

Comment: I did disable it and added SKIP_INCLUDES. Looks like this now: WIN32;_DEBUG;_CONSOLE;SKIP_INCLUDES;%(PreprocessorDefinitions). And Now have a whole new list of errors :(
Starting with Error 122 error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\core.hpp 2953 1 OpenCVI
What should I do now?

Comment: @WikiMalik Could you please post several of them?

Comment: I know it's terrifying and nerve breaking trying to help someone in the limited information (Like over phone). You literally have to be wired in; I'm open to skype screen share, TeamViewer etc) if that's a possible option.

Comment: Output and Errors: http://opencvtesting101.blogspot.com/2016/12/output-after-skipincludes.html

Comment: @WikiMalik Send me please your complete solution. Looks like you have broken project templates or something wrong with Visual Studio. I saw such strange behavior after update from Win 7 to Win 10

Comment: Alright, here's the link to the Zip File: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_wIR1AsbUQvZUxGV1hRb1NCeG8

Comment: @WikiMalik In `Main.cpp` try to include only the following headers: `#include <string>`, `#include <iostream>`, `#include <vector>`, `#include <map>`, `#include <complex>`, `#include <assert.h>`, `#include<opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>`. Header order should be preserved.

Comment: I did, preserving the order, and now I have 224 Errors. Did the project compiled alright on your end?

Comment: @WikiMalik Yes, it's compiled properly. Probably, you could try to reinstall your Visual Studio, as I think it is the reason of the problem.

Comment: Could you look at the errors once more for me before giving up, afterward, I'll accept my doom.

http://opencvtesting101.blogspot.com/2016/12/output-errors-after-including-headers.html

Comment: Actually, I have switched between VS 2010, VS 2011, VS 2012 just to get OpenCV working. I got happy when v2012 did compiled at the first time and I finally got to see a picture display, same code, same configuration as was shown in the tutorial. And then I included imgproc, which became the mother of all issues.

Comment: @WikiMalik Yes, strange errors still there. E.g. `error C2039: 'vector' : is not a member of 'std'`, but it's explicitly included by `#include <vector>`.

Comment: I'm a writer basically, doing this for experimental purposes. I need to make a library that I wanna eventually ship to Unity3D where I'm more familiar with working framework of 3D and javascript. If you have any opinion in that regard, that'll also be helpful, but I really need to a platform tell the machines something and learn something in return.