# SOIL.lib can not be linked in the C++ project

Tags: c++, soil

I'm setting up the soil for my simple c++ game. But there are something wrong with my SOIL setup.

I used vs2019 in the Win10, and I have also successfully set up my openGL (through the test sample).
But when I tried to import the SOIL and built the project, there was always show me link error 1104 with 'SOIL.lib'. 
Although I have tried to rename the libSOIL.a or build the SOIL.lib by source file, it also gave me the same result.

```
1 > -- -- --ビルド開始: プロジェクト: wanggame, 構成: Debug Win32-- -- --
1 > LINK: fatal error LNK1104: file 'Simple OpenGL Image Library/projects/VC9/Release/SOIL.lib' can not be used
1 > project "wanggame.vcxproj" building error.
```

Comment: Are you building for 64-bit but SOIL.lib is 32-bit, perhaps?

Comment: Sure. I tried to rebuid it to the 64bit by source file, but it still can not be used .orz

Comment: Maybe this is your issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133698/why-does-fatal-error-lnk1104-cannot-open-file-c-program-obj-occur-when-i-c

Comment: Also check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk1104?view=vs-2019